# When can I update 22.04 to kernel 6.1?

Tags: kernel, updates, kubuntu

I note that kernel version 6.1 has been released, but it is not yet in either the mainline repository or the kubuntu update repository.  Hope it is available soon because earlier kernel versions don't recognize my laptop keyboard!

Comment: You can hope, but it won't be in 22.04.2 (January 2023, HWE kernel 5.19). HWE kernels are bumped every six months, about 3-4 months after the standard 6-month releases, and using the same kernels as those standard releases.

Comment: I read that it is possible to update kernel directly not using Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @Mahler yes but not recommended. It will lack all the Ubuntu specific alterations. v6.1 did not build yet looking at the status. v6 does so I added that one in my answer.

Comment: "because earlier kernel versions don't recognize my laptop keyboard!" I doubt v6.1 is going to fix that. Internal keyboards are hard wired and use generic drivers to support a 104 keys lay-out. Only keys using 3 dwords need specific support from a driver.

Comment: I have been using kernel 6.0.8 but had also problems with keyboard and mouse so far the best kernel working for me is 5.19.028.29 for Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Well 6.1-rc5 does recognize my keyboard!  That's what I am using now, but I was hoping to replace it with something more stable.  From what I have  read here, I  guess I will just watch and wait for kubuntu to catch up with the kernel releases, and hope that the rc5 version doesn't "bite me".

Comment: For the record, my laptop is an Asus model S5402Z.  Kernel versions 6.0.x don't work, 6.1-rc5 does.

Answer (score 3):

Never.

> Hope it is available soon because earlier kernel versions

You can try [Canonical’s mainline repo](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) to install 6.1. NOT recommended though mainline builds do not come with any warranty, support, or testing to ensure they are free problems. Use at your own risk.

- download "headers", "linux-modules", "linux-image-unsigned" for the version you want and then do

edit: below is for installing v6, not v6.1; the site shows v6.1 build FAILED so you might need to wait a bit for v6.1. rc5 is avaible; higher failed building.

---

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.0/amd64/linux-headers-6.0.0-060000_6.0.0-060000.202210022231_all.deb
 sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.0/amd64/linux-headers-6.0.0-060000-generic_6.0.0-060000.202210022231_amd64.deb
 sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.0/amd64/linux-modules-6.0.0-060000-generic_6.0.0-060000.202210022231_amd64.deb
 sudo wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.0/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-6.0.0-060000-generic_6.0.0-060000.202210022231_amd64.deb
 sudo apt install ./linux-*.deb
```

> don't recognize my laptop keyboard!

6.1 is not likely to fix that.

Comment: Version 6.0 is available in ordinary repository. I use 5.17.

Answer (score 3):

I had installed the 6.1 kernel yesterday. It is available in the Jammy 22.04 LTS Repository. No problem with this kernel so far. Snap packages work fine.

```
sudo apt install linux-image-6.1.0-1006-oem linux-headers-6.1.0-1006-oem
```

Comment: Do you care to share the command that you used to install Linux 6.1 LTS in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: 6.1 is not LTS kernel. I have added the command to install the kernel.

Comment: Trying a random OEM will indeed work for some people, but not for others. Don't do this unless you know how to revert.

Answer (score 3):

like @Mahler said, but you can install the kernel stack with the linux-oem-22.04c metapackage to ensure that 6.1-oem is up to date

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04c
```

Comment: I usually do kernel update manually. Presently I don't want to move from 6.1 that seems to be LTS.

Comment: well this oem-22.04c meta-package does bind with 6.1, do an apt list linux-oem-22.04* and we can get thee variants which is a b and c, a seems to tied with 5.17, b to 6.0 and c to 6.1, any updates to 6.1 will be notified and handled automatically when we use the meta-package. thus create some convienience when updating the 6.1 branch without installing the kernel suite manually

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Linux 6.1, I recommend the Xanmod kernel, although it is unofficial.

You can also install packages for Ubuntu from ppa.

*<sub>Note: I am a resident of Japan.  This is a Deepl translation.</sub>*